# Rails Application on Heroku doesn't Recognize pg Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

pretty new heroku so excuse my noobness.

Trying to deploy an application that works fine on my local machine to heroku.

It deploys fine after

```
git push heroku master
```

But I get the following errors when I look at the heroku logs:

```
2013-10-09T02:56:42.363522+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands/server.rb:48:in `app'
2013-10-09T02:56:42.363141+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/config.ru:in `<main>'
2013-10-09T02:56:42.363522+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `<top (required)>'
2013-10-09T02:56:42.363522+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/rack-1.5.2/lib/rack/server.rb:314:in `wrapped_app'
2013-10-09T02:56:42.406543+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
2013-10-09T02:56:42.406543+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 4.0.0 application starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:44409
2013-10-09T02:56:42.363522+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-4.0.0/lib/rails/commands.rb:73:in `tap'
2013-10-09T02:56:42.406543+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting WEBrick
2013-10-09T02:56:42.406543+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
2013-10-09T02:56:43.780131+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2013-10-09T02:56:43.770751+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2013-10-09T02:59:44.437016+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=career-agent.herokuapp.com fwd="74.9.178.228" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T02:59:44.746548+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=career-agent.herokuapp.com fwd="74.9.178.228" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T03:04:32.057876+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/favicon.ico host=career-agent.herokuapp.com fwd="74.9.178.228" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T03:04:31.565122+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path=/ host=career-agent.herokuapp.com fwd="74.9.178.228" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2013-10-09T03:06:56.946173+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2013-10-09T03:07:02.040757+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bin/rails server -p 10939 -e $RAILS_ENV`
2013-10-09T03:07:09.880708+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:55:in `resolve_hash_connection'
2013-10-09T03:07:09.880708+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-4.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:38:in `instance_eval'
2013-10-09T03:07:09.880708+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:46:in `resolve_string_connection'
2013-10-09T03:07:09.880708+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.0/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/connection_specification.rb:58:in `rescue in resolve_hash_connection': Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile. (Gem::LoadError)
```

I added `gem pg` to my gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'protected_attributes'

group :production do
  # gems specifically for Heroku go here
  gem "pg"
end

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.0.0'

# Use mysql as the database for Active Record
gem 'mysql2'

# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'

# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
# gem 'therubyracer', platforms: :ruby

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'

# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'

# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 1.2'

group :doc do
  # bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end

# Use ActiveModel has_secure_password
# gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Use unicorn as the app server
# gem 'unicorn'

# Use Capistrano for deployment
# gem 'capistrano', group: :development

# Use debugger
# gem 'debugger', group: [:development, :test]
```

When I do `bundle show pg`:

```
/Users/Calvino/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448/gems/pg-0.16.0
```

I've already run `bundle install`:

```
Calvins-Air:LifeAgent Calvino$ bundle install
Using rake (10.1.0) 
Using i18n (0.6.5) 
Using minitest (4.7.5) 
Using multi_json (1.7.9) 
Using atomic (1.1.13) 
Using thread_safe (0.1.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.37) 
Using activesupport (4.0.0) 
Using builder (3.1.4) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using rack (1.5.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.2) 
Using actionpack (4.0.0) 
Using mime-types (1.25) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.15) 
Using mail (2.5.4) 
Using actionmailer (4.0.0) 
Using activemodel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord-deprecated_finders (1.0.3) 
Using arel (4.0.0) 
Using activerecord (4.0.0) 
Using coffee-script-source (1.6.3) 
Using execjs (2.0.1) 
Using coffee-script (2.2.0) 
Using thor (0.18.1) 
Using railties (4.0.0) 
Using coffee-rails (4.0.0) 
Using hike (1.2.3) 
Using jbuilder (1.5.1) 
Using jquery-rails (3.0.4) 
Using json (1.8.0) 
Using mysql2 (0.3.13) 
Using pg (0.16.0) 
Using protected_attributes (1.0.3) 
Using bundler (1.3.5) 
Using tilt (1.4.1) 
Using sprockets (2.10.0) 
Using sprockets-rails (2.0.0) 
Using rails (4.0.0) 
Using rdoc (3.12.2) 
Using sass (3.2.10) 
Using sass-rails (4.0.0) 
Using sdoc (0.3.20) 
Using turbolinks (1.3.0) 
Using uglifier (2.2.1) 
Your bundle is complete!
Use `bundle show [gemname]` to see where a bundled gem is installed.
```

I've been googling for hours to no avail. Any help? Clearly pg is found on my system, why hasn't it been found on Heroku?

Comment: have you solved problem or still getting issue?

Comment: Thanks to gabrielhilal I think I solved my original problem. But I'm now getting a new error. Edited my original post.

Comment: the edit is irrelevant please remove edited part, as it was not error you just forgot to run your migrations to creation tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you probably didn't push to heroku after adding the `pg` gem locally.... try the following:

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'pg gem added'
git push
git push heroku
```

I hope it helps...

Comment: Weird, I'm using github GUI and I know I already committed and synced but this seemed to fix my original problem. But now I'm getting a new error, will edit my original post.

Answer (score 0):

I also see `mysql2` gem included in your `Gemfile`. Not sure if that is clashing with `pg`. Try restrict `mysql2 gem` to non production environments only.